# Fetch and Update large amount of data in postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, batch-processing

I am building a web application and using postgreSQL as database. I need to fetch and update thousands of rows every 5-10 mins. Let's say i have 1M rows with this following schema in my table:

```
ServiceStatus {
 id: string,
 userid: string,
 status: string,
}
```

I will be fetching all the rows based on service status (let's assume 100,000 rows every 5 mins) and based on the status i'll do some processing and update status in db. As i said i'll do this every 5-10 mins. What's the most efficient approach to this?

Comment: Does `status` have an index on it? Provide an example of the query you intend to run.  Does each `status` cover the 100,000 rows or are you going to be fetching for multiple `status` values?

Comment: status can be either active or pending. I'll be fetching all the servicestatus that are pending. (Fetch all data from servicestatus table). For eg let's say we have 10 rows out of which 6 are pending and 4 are active, In this case I want to fetch all 6 rows and do some processing and then update status based on result. It's not that complicated we can simply use select and where statement to filter data, fetch all the values and than update it, but the problem is we are doing it on large scale and more frequently and for that some optimization is required.

Comment: So are you actually seeing a slow down? If so the results of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the query would be helpful?

Comment: Can the "some processing" be done in the database, or does it have to be done outside?

Comment: @jjanes outside, I'll be using status id to interact with external api and get latest status.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching 100,000 row once every 5 minutes will not be strenuous.  Updating them should not be either, but probably don't update one just to set it back to the same value as it already holds.

If this turns out to be a problem, it will come down to some detail you haven't described to us, and which we can't guess.